# Вынести значение переменной в глобальную область

Tags: javascript, foreach, const

На странице есть несколько section, и ссылок

я перебираю их и создаю в них id с названием класса

Теперь я хочу каждой ссылке вписать href с классами секций.

Как можно вынести значение className в глобальную область видимости

```
const body = document.body;

const pageSliderButtons = Array.from(body.getElementsByTagName('a'));

const sections = Array.from(body.getElementsByTagName('section'));

sections.forEach((section, index) => {
  const className = section.className;
  section.setAttribute('id', `#${className}`);
});
```

Comment: `const body = document.body;` по структуре выше чем `const className = section.className;` надеюсь ясно намекнул

Comment: @Capital300 вам надо именно создать ссылки на секции, или __вынести className в глобальную область видимости__?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вопрос.

Comment: @PeterKolosov, планировал создать массив с классами секций, чтобы потом записать в массив ссылок href с названиями классов секций.

Comment: @Capital300 а, ну значит я правильно ответил 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам надо поместить переменную в глобальную область видимости.

То есть, код будет выглядеть примерно так:

```js
const body = document.body;

const pageSliderButtons = Array.from(body.getElementsByTagName('a'));

const sections = Array.from(body.getElementsByTagName('section'));
let className;

sections.forEach((section, index) => {
  className = section.className;
  section.setAttribute('id', `#${className}`);
});
```

Но непонятно, для чего вам нужно выносить переменную в глобальную область видимости. Ведь `forEach` будет перебирать все элементы, и после выполнения `forEach` в переменной `className` окажется НЕ значения всех `.className`, а только значение `.className` у последнего элемента.

Если вам нужно вынести все значения классов в глобальную область видимости, вам нужно:

1. Создать пустой массив.
2. В цикле `forEach` в каждой итерации выполнять добавление `className` (класса) в массив классов.
3. Потом после цикла `forEach` можно спокойно использовать массив с классами.

Это будет выглядеть примерно так:

```js
const body = document.body;

const pageSliderButtons = Array.from(body.getElementsByTagName('a'));

const sections = Array.from(body.getElementsByTagName('section'));
// объявить массив имён классов для последующего заполнения
let classNames = [];

sections.forEach((section, index) => {
  // получить само имя класса
  const className = section.className;
  // добавить (push) имя класса в массив
  classNames.push(className);
  // дальше можно делать всё, что вы хотите
  section.setAttribute('id', `#${className}`);
});
```

И кстати, атрибут `id` принимает значения только без `#`, потому что он и так автоматически подставляется.

То есть, надо заменить:

```js
  section.setAttribute('id', `#${className}`);
```

на:

```js
  section.setAttribute('id', `${className}`);
```

(без `#` в значение `id`)

---

Я точно не уверен, отвечает ли это на поставленный вопрос, поэтому, если так, то прошу не минусовать, а объяснить, что я не прав, и конкретнее объяснить вопрос.

Comment: Если ответ вам ещё и понравился, можете проголосовать за, @Capital300 :)